# How to show txt files in HTML

Tags: html

I want to show txt files in HTML files.
I find a simple way that is to use iframe tag of html

```
<iframe src="ｔｅｓｔ.txt" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"/>
```

But it's not friendly to user. Is there any other better ways.

Comment: What does it look like? do you have a live example?

Comment: I would do this in a JavaScript script like presented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript.

Comment: You could create a css and format 'txt text' there (font, colors, etc) to make it look better. Or if you have a different issue, +1 to @KeesSonnema

Comment: Do you want to how to format the text file or how to correctly output/write a text file to the html document?

Answer (score 1):

several options:
 - javascript/ajax
 - php

this thread has some good suggestions: http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/html-xhtml-xml/53593-how-display-text-file-using-php-html.html

Comment: Yes, we can use javascript or ajax. But there is a problem. ajax can get the txt content but all the contents will show in one line instead of multiple lines. It's hard for me to split it. What do you think?

Comment: It depends if you don't have any clear line endings what you could do is split on periods, exlamation marks etc. so that each sentence starts on a new line. A better way would be to decide a number of characters for each line. Then you just look for the closest space character and split on that.