# read a file line by line using javaScript

Tags: javascript, readfile

i want to Build Android Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I need to read file. A local file that contain questions (A data base of question). i think it is possible with javaScript , is it true? please help and share your information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read text file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using **HTML5 FileReader API**. The best source for that is , http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.

Scroll down to reading files.

```
FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding)
```

Split the content with EOL character for UTF-8.

Note: By default the string is decoded as **'UTF-8'**.

Comment: thanks , can i get a static path file to this function , i have a data base store in a file and I want to read this data base so it's path is specified. can i load this file automatically?    thanks for your answer

Comment: I dont think its possible to access local hard disk. JavaScript doesnt have access.

Comment: You can run a local server on your computer and put those files in it. Access it from there.

Comment: every thing is static, i mean i don't want to connect to server.i am just using html,jS & css that can be run on mobile like games that every body install on mobile without need to use internet. sorry for my pure English , i hope understand my mean :(

Comment: You can store and retrieve data using localstorage. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ . But you cannot access anything outside that :|