# How to read local files

Tags: javascript, console

So I was looking around but I couldn't find an answer for this. I'm not talking about reading them from a website, but when you type code in to the browsers console how can you make it read a certain local file and output its contents in the console?

Comment: There's not much difference between executing JS on the browser's console and on a web page. If a web site can't do it, the console can't do it either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read text file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the browser environment, you have to first set up your HTML to read in the file via an input (with type=file). Once read in, you have manipulate that file using JavaScript. Take a look at this example: [HTML5 Rocks - Reading Local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

If you're using the Node.js environment, there are built in functions that allow you to easily read files from your local environment. Take a look at this documentation: [Node.js Documentation - fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)

Hope this helps.