# Javascript create array from local file.txt

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I have this text file in the same directory with my javascript program:

test.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to load the data in array.
So at the end i will have a array variable as follow:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: local as in, on your filesystem or local on your web server that is serving the .js file?

Comment: Are you using node.js or are you trying to do this in the browser?

Comment: Check this [how to read text file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)

Comment: @SergeyMaksimenko Thank you It work but i take a syntax error in test.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XMLHTTPRequest to load the text from file, like jQuery does, then you can put it something like this:

```
var array = [];
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
        // Now convert it into array using regex
        array = text.split(/\n|\r/g);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

this way you will get in `array` form, the text from test.txt file.

*I am assuming test.txt in same folder as script does*

Comment: why not use split with regex direct, instead of replacing line breaks with comma?

Answer (score 2):

**try this way**

```
<script>
fs.readFile('test.txt',"utf-8",function(err,data){
        if(err) throw err;
        var array = Array.from(data) //convert char array
        console.log(array)

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your text as a string when you get a text file:

```
var text = "1\n2\n3\n4\n5";
```

You need to use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create an array:

```
text = text.split("\n");
```

After you will get an array:

```
console.log(text); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Could you tell me, please, what is wrong with this approach? Why you voted against?

Comment: I don't know who voted down but i think because you didn't explain how get a text file as a string.

Comment: Thanks, but nobody asked that.

Comment: yes, the question is about how to read the data in from a local text file. Not how to split an already existing string into an array.