# How do I save JSON to local text file

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have a javascript object that looks like this :

```
  var data = {
      name: "cliff",
      age: "34",
      name: "ted",
      age: "42",
      name: "bob",
      age: "12"
    }

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

I stringify it to convert to JSON. How do I save this JSON to a local text file so I can open it, say, in Notepad etc.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test.txt", jsonData, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Browser (webapi):

```
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
download(jsonData, 'json.txt', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou. I know it's a different question completely, how difficult is it to get chrome to load JSON from local file ? Read a few places it's not possible due to Chrome's security...

Comment: it's possible, you just have to use input tag with type=file, like presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript

Comment: you have just saved me a lot of time. Very much appreciated. Thank you :))

Comment: I get `[object Object]` when I do this

Comment: @JackNicholson I also just got `[object Object]`..  I had to call `JSON.stringify()` first, and pass *that* value, rather than the object itself.

Comment: I added JSON.stringify() inside the function, inside a if checking for contentType == 'application/json'. Tks for that code. Works like a charm.

Comment: It worked for me, but what if i don't want to replace the file but instead append text to file?

Comment: After `a.click()`, we should call `revokeObjectURL` in order to let the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer: `URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href).` More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL.

Comment: is possible to save to a custom folder? if I use "myfolder/myfile.json" it is converted to myfolder_myfile.json

Comment: @Enrique In node.js you can of course. In webapi user chooses destination directory, so no, you can't.

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach to save the file in "Save As" mode? (so I can get a confirmation dialog to possibly save in a different location than the default Downloads folder)  Thanks!

Comment: I think question was not about Node.js explicitly. thanks

Answer (score 42):

It's my solution to save local data to txt file.

```js
function export2txt() {
  const originalData = {
    members: [{
        name: "cliff",
        age: "34"
      },
      {
        name: "ted",
        age: "42"
      },
      {
        name: "bob",
        age: "12"
      }
    ]
  };

  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(originalData, null, 2)], {
    type: "text/plain"
  }));
  a.setAttribute("download", "data.txt");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="export2txt()">Export data to local txt file</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fantastic and simple solution using pure javascript .

Comment: It's just simply awesome!!  :D

Comment: Thanks for the indentation tip for better json format `JSON.stringify(originalData, null, 2)`. Also naming the file "data.json" should be more appropriate if it is a json file.

Comment: I second @Patronaut comment. Plus change `type: "text/plain"` to: `type: "application/json"`

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution on pure js. You can do it with html5 saveAs. For example this lib could be helpful: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Look at the demo: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

P.S. There is no information about json save, but you can do it changing file type to `"application/json"` and format to `.json`

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'

let data = { a: 'aaa' , b: 'bbb' }

let blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: 'application/json' })
    
saveAs(blob, 'export.json')
```

Comment: "application/json" and .json works well with html file system. Also using this to prevent any json parse errors such as "Unexpected token ? in JSON". Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Took [dabeng's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60377870/5217142) and I have transcribed it as a class method.

```
class JavascriptDataDownloader {

    constructor(data={}) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    download (type_of = "text/plain", filename= "data.txt") {
        let body = document.body;
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.data, null, 2)], {
            type: type_of
        }));
        a.setAttribute("download", filename);
        body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        body.removeChild(a);
    }
} 

new JavascriptDataDownloader({"greetings": "Hello World"}).download();
```

Comment: I like this answer because it even works in console. thanks

Comment: ...where is the file saved on a iPhone device???