# equations on cells generated from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a small JSON file which looks like this

```
var myData = [{
   "No": 1,
   "Ticker": "WSI",
   "Units": 72,
   "Price In": 15,
   "Entry Value": "",

 },
 {
   "No": 2,
   "Ticker": "DE",
   "Units": 25,
   "Price In": 15,
   "Entry Value": "",

 },
```

and so on...

Additionally a script that generates a simple table:

```
var myTable = '<table>';
myTable += '<tr>';

for (var x in myData[0]) {
  myTable += '<th>' + x + '</th>';
}
myTable += '</tr>';

for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  myTable += '<tr>';
  for (var x in myData[i]) {
    myTable += '<td>' + myData[i][x] + '</td>';
  }
}
myTable += '</table>';
document.getElementById('jstable').innerHTML = myTable;
```

Two questions:

1. How do I proceed with doing various equations on JSON? For Example last column "Entry Value" should return the result of "Units * Price In"

Something like this doesn't work:

```
var myData = [{
   "No": 1,
   "Ticker": "WSI",
   "Units": 72,
   "Price In": 15,
   "Entry Value": myData.Units * myData.["Price In"],
 },
```

2. As a beginner, what topics should I research in order to be able edit columns after I click on them

Thank you

Comment: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in your code. _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myData = [{
   "No": 1,
   "Ticker": "WSI",
   "Units": 72,
   "Price In": 15,
   "Entry Value": "",

 },
 {
   "No": 2,
   "Ticker": "DE",
   "Units": 25,
   "Price In": 15,
   "Entry Value": "",

 }];
        function getDynamicData(obj, key)
        {
            var value;
            switch(x)
            {
                case "Entry Value" : value = obj["Units"] * obj["Price In"]; break;
                default : value = obj[key];
            }
            return value;
        }
        
        function addListeners()
        {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll("table td");
            console.log(elems);
            for(var i=0,n=elems.length; i<n;i++)
            {
                elems[i].addEventListener("click", editValue, true);
            }
        }
        
        function editValue(elem)
        {
            var oldvalue = elem.target.textContent;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.value = oldvalue;
            var savebtn = document.createElement("button");
            savebtn.textContent = "Save";
            var cancelbtn = document.createElement("button");
            cancelbtn.textContent = "Cancel";
            savebtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                elem.target.textContent = input.value;
            });
            cancelbtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                elem.target.textContent = oldvalue;
            });
            elem.target.appendChild(input);
            elem.target.appendChild(savebtn);
            elem.target.appendChild(cancelbtn);
        }

        var myTable = '<table>';
        myTable += '<tr>';

        for (var x in myData[0]) {
          myTable += '<th>' + x + '</th>';
        }
        myTable += '</tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
          myTable += '<tr>';
          for (var x in myData[i]) {
            myTable += '<td>' + getDynamicData(myData[i],x) + '</td>';
          }
        }
        myTable += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('jstable').innerHTML = myTable;
        addListeners();
```

```html
<div id="jstable"></div>
```

1. To get data dynamically, better have a method like `getDynamicData()` and handle the cases inside switch. In need of no dynamic data, by default, it returns the 
   value.
2. On clicking, you have to manipulate the DOM i.e., you have to add EventListener to that element, manipulate DOM elements and insert a `input` element to edit the value, insert a `button` say Save/Ok/Submit, add eventListeners to those elements and again you need to manipulate the DOM.

You need to refer topics on [DOM Manipulation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp), [addEventListeners](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Also make sure you learn everything with cross-browser support.

The addEventListeners I did in the example will not work on IE. It has another way. You may want to learn that too.

Comment: Wow this is the most incredible help I've ever received! I will study the code for days before I will understand it very well :) Just one las question: of course to be able to actually save the file on the server I'd need a server side language (NodeJS, PHP etc.) but if I want to keep files on my local disk - do I still have to create virtual server (say in node)? Sooo many topics to learn to create my first project, so I'd prefer to focus on JS only. Thank you again!!!

Comment: do you mean saving the edited data in to a file in local disk ?

Comment: yes, saving the myData object into a file. I know that for putting it on a server I'd have to use server side language, but what if I decide to save files locally only?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(myData)` since myData is a object. And for saving you can refer this.
[Save JSON data into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file)