# How to create and export text file based on dynamic data using angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

here i unable to solve a issue i am having table with 2 columns in the second column a button will be placed and on that button click the data from the column send to a URL as param and it will call the server and download the data into array now can i export that data into text file

[image]

After clicking on the update button it will take the firstname as call a service url and i am getting the data in the

```
this.service.update(firstname).subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

now how can i export this **res data** to the text file

**The response data has to be exported to textfile so that user can open that textfile and view data**

Comment: What do you mean by exporting?

Comment: what ever data which is there in variable has to be exported to textfile

Comment: And what do you want to do with that export? Should it be downloaded, should it be written to the server's hard drive, should it be stored in a database?

Comment: The response data has to be exported to textfile so that user can open that textfile and view data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file