# Import text file to R and change it's format

Tags: r

I have a data in text file. The example of the text file looks like this:

```
"vLatitude ='23.8145833';       
vLongitude ='90.4043056';
vcontents ='LRP: LRPS</br>Start of Road From the End of Banani Rail Crossing Over Pass</br>Division:Gazipur</br>Sub-Division:Tongi';
                
vLocations = new Array(vcontents, vLatitude, vLongitude);   
locations.push(vLocations);"
```

**Can I change it to like this in R?**

eg.

```
  latitute  longtitude  contents
23.8145833  90.4043056  LRP: LRPS Start...Tongi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

That looks a lot like javascript code. Execute the javascript (using a web browser) and [save the result to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file), then open the file with R with `jsonlite`.

With your example, create this file and save it as `my_page.html`:

```
<html>
<header>
<script>

// Initialize locations to be able to push more values in it
// probably not required with your full code
var locations = [];

vLatitude ='23.8145833';       
vLongitude ='90.4043056';
vcontents ='LRP: LRPS</br>Start of Road From the End of Banani Rail Crossing Over Pass</br>Division:Gazipur</br>Sub-Division:Tongi';
                
vLocations = new Array(vcontents, vLatitude, vLongitude);   
locations.push(vLocations);

// convert locations to json
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(locations);

// actually write the json to file
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
download(jsonData, 'export_json.txt', 'text/plain');


</script>
</header>
<body>
Download should start automatically. You can look at the web console for errors.
</body>
</html>
```

When you open it with your web browser it should "download" a file, that you can open with R:

```
jsonlite::read_json("export_json.txt",simplifyVector = TRUE)
```

One problem is that the javascript code is created an array without names. So the names are not exported. I don't see how you could make javascript export it.

### Solution 2

Instead of relying on a browser to execute the javascript code, you could do it directly in R with [a javascript engine](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html). It should give you the same result, but makes communication between the two easier.

### Solution 3

If the file really looks like that all along, you *might* be able to remove the javascript lines that organize the arrays, and only keep the lines that define variables. In R, the symbols `=` and `;` are technically valid, it's not too hard to rewrite the javascript into R code. Note this solution could be very fragile depending on what else is in your javascript code!

```
js_script <- "var locations = [];

vLatitude ='23.8145833';       
vLongitude ='90.4043056';
vcontents ='LRP: LRPS</br>Start of Road From the End of Banani Rail Crossing Over Pass</br>Division:Gazipur</br>Sub-Division:Tongi';
                
vLocations = new Array(vcontents, vLatitude, vLongitude);   
locations.push(vLocations);

// convert locations to json
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(locations);" %>%
  str_split(pattern = "\n", simplify=TRUE) %>%
  as.character() %>%
  str_trim()


# Find the lines that look like defining variables
js_script <- js_script[str_detect(js_script, pattern = "^\\w+ ?= ?'.*' ?;$")]

# make it into an R expression
r_code <- str_remove(js_script, ";$") %>%
  paste(collapse = ",")

r_code <- paste0("c(", r_code, ")")

# Execute
eval(str2expression(r_code))
```