# How to store Form Input Values in JSON File Using Only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I want to store the form input values directly to the JSON File without using PHP, Angular Js, Node Js or NPM using JavaScript. But I didn't have any idea how to do it. Please help me out!!!

Comment: You need to send the form data to server and write to file there. Or use a remote data storage service. Also your question is far too broad. Please take the time to read [ask]

Comment: Check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a json file and then download the file to your system.
Check out this link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file
```

Answer (score -1):

JS itself does not have access to file system