# FullCalendar JS how save data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How can I save the data? In json or in any other format.

1. Its demo [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/demos)
2. Docs [Date Clicking & Selecting](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting)
3. My main page:
   [image]
4. Html code where i load data from list:

.

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="../lib/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../lib/main.js"></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      initialDate: '2020-09-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      select: function(arg) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: title,
            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay
          })
        }
        calendar.unselect()
      },
      eventClick: function(arg) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
          arg.event.remove()
        }
      },
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2020-09-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2020-09-07',
          end: '2020-09-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2020-09-09T16:00:00'
        }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();});
</script>
</head>
<body class="">

  <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard"><div class="fc-header-toolbar fc-toolbar fc-toolbar-ltr"><div class="fc-toolbar-chunk"><div class="fc-button-group">

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query data using `calendar.getEvents()` and then save the file using e.g. [How do I save JSON to local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file)

Try to put more effort into reading the docs, FullCalendar has a very nice documentation.