# how to change code read data from localStorage to text file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code read data but it read with localStorage.  I want to change read localStorage to read a text file. because when I switched to another computer file data will not be displayed. Please help me.

**data in text file**

```
var Hello = {
    "nodes": {
        "Hello": {
            "label": "Hello"
        },
        "textbox": {
            "label": "Help me please!"
        },
        "due_date": {
            "label": "2016-04-16"
        }
    }
}
```

**code read data**

```
loaddata = function () {  

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('title_' + i)) {
                createNewTile(
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('title_' + i))
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking here!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13709482/438992

Comment: What exactly you are asking? Are you trying to copy data from local storage into a text file?

Comment: You can't normally write files locally using JavaScript in the browser.