# How to import a text file content to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get content of text file. In addition, how can I use in JavaScript? e.g line by line or array?

Comment: server side or client side?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript

Comment: Best to use AJAX for this. There is also a `FileReader` JavaScript Constructor, but it won't work on all Browsers.

Comment: PHPglue only if there is a purpose for transferring the file contents... Plus, the acronym AJAX has lost almost all of its meaning.

Comment: Oh, you edited your comment. Yes, `FileReader` would still be asynchronous but we can stop saying AJAX as a catch-all for anything that is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you target client-side .

Then if your text file is hosted under the same project where page HTML contains or import the following script :

```
$.get('/docs/file.txt',{},function(content){
      let lines=content.split('\n');

       console.log(`"file.txt" contains ${lines.length} lines`)
      console.log(`First line : ${lines[0]}`)

});
```

Assume that if we have the following routing rule :

- `http://localhost/`   ---> `/var/www/html/index.html`

`/docs/file.txt` should follow this rule :

- `http://localhost/docs/file.txt` --> `/var/www/html/docs/file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the node `fs` module for this. You can read and write content both sync and async depending on what you're trying to do with it.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html