# I'm not sure on how to continue with this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a file and assign it to a array and randomly get a string from the array and print it on the html. I have done this whole project in python. But I've never programmed with JavaScript and am not sure how to proceed. I think the issue may be with the file assigning to array but I am confused.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Julia Mount</title>
</head>
<body onload="ll()">
<style>
    body{
    background-color:lime;  
}
#wat{
    padding-top:auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fs = require("fs");
    var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt");
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")
    var ll = ["wat","idk"   
];
               //stuff im trying
    //var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length); 
    //var randomElement = textArray[randomIndex];
    //document.getElementById("ll").innerHTML = randomElement;
    ll.toString();
    //document.getElementById("ll").innerHTML = ll;

</script>
<h1 id="wat">I love </h1>
    <p></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write($ll)     
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the other answer, you're trying to use a server side ( nodeJs ) code to get the file in the browser, to get the content of a `.txt` file in the browser ( `html` side ) you'll need to do an [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) request with [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp), wrap it in a function and return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make sure everything is executing [Synchronously](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/javascript-execution-of-synchronous-and-asynchronous-codes-40f3a199e687)

replace theses lines :

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt");
var textByLine = text.split("\n");
```

with :

```
var textByLine;

function readTextFile(file, cb) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
          resolve(rawFile.responseText);
        }
      }
    }

    rawFile.send(null);
  });

}

readTextFile('mytext.txt').then((text) => {
  textByLine = text.split("\n");
});

// ... rest of you code ...
```

Comment: Its going better, got some other stuff im working on now though. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no native mechanisms to access files. It depends on functions being provided by the host environment.

> ```
> var fs = require("fs");
> var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt");
> ```

These are functions provided by Node.js but not by web browsers.

To run this code, you need to remove it from the HTML page and run it using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript) for information about reading files using a JS embedded in a webpage.

Comment: I'm trying to get this all in a single html file to send to my gf. Il just have to remove that