# <script> and JavaScript not working in HTML file for all browsers after XMLHTTPREQUEST

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Hello I am new to JavaScript. I have looked through other posts but I cannot resolve my issue.

Earlier I was attempting to play around with the following script found here ([How to read text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)).
I got it working successfully SEVERAL times:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Read File (via AJAX)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'test.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="test.txt"  onclick="loadFile()" />
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

While testing this script, all of a sudden it stopped working! I have assured that my content blockers are disabled and javascript is enabled on my web browsers. I am not sure if I locked up my web browsers ability to use javascript while using this XMLHTTPREQUEST or possibly overloaded it. I even tried inserting a reader.abort() function to possibly close the request if it was still open somehow. I tried inserting alert() functions to troubleshoot that did not work. I tried restarting my computer that did not work. I am using a MAC and have tried the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari which all do not work with javascript now.

It is so bad that I CAN'T even get this simple javascript example to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type=“text/javascript”>
document.write(“<h1>This is a test</h1>”);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

PLEASE HELP! I don't know what I did or how to fix the issue.

Comment: `document.write(“<h1>This is a test</h1>”);` is invalid syntax. Good rule of thumb, never use so-called "smart" quotes in programming, always use straight quotes.

Comment: Wow. I was on this issue for 3-4 hours! I can't believe that worked. Thanks @CertainPerformance. I am surprised it worked the first couple times unless the quotes somehow got changed as I was altering things. I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Learn to use the debugger in the browser!

Answer (score 0):

Above script works only if you're loading the text file from a server. Make sure the file is located in the same place as your html file on the server and load the page with your server address. Most likely thing you're doing wrong is you're trying to access client's file. It doesn't work because that will be HUGE security breach, only the client can send you a file to read *(If that is your intended purpose, then I advise you to use FileReader, example code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript))*.

About your second script, you're using “ instead of ".