# How can I acess a website's localstorage from another website?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to access website A's localstorage from website B's script, how could I do that?

If that is not possible in any way how could I save a string from website A (using a JS script) to my computer and how could I read it from website B's script?

Comment: Do you want to save it on the client computer or the server?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: @Barmar client computer

Comment: @Joundill I haven't written code yet. Because I  can't write code without these informations.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to make a .txt file in the same root directory and provide its path to where you want to use the string.
If you want to use it in a javascript file, you can refer: [How to read text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)

I hope this helps!