# AngularJS File placing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Do I need to place the files in a local-server or any server to get the results?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta char-set = "UTF-8">
        <title>AngularJS | Passing Data between Different Scopes</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app = "mainApp">
        <div ng-controller = "app">
            <li ng-repeat = "i in myRange">
                {{i}} <br/>
            </li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller.js:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('app', function($scope) {
    var range = 10;
    var myRange = [];
    for (i = 0; i<range; i++)
    {
        myRange.push(i);
    }
    $scope.myRange = myRange;
});
```

When i'm running using localhost it gets the result i wanted. But when I run it without using any server or local-server it shows only the html page, not returning data from controller.js file. As i know this must work without using of any local-server. what's the wrong here?

Edit: 
When i run the html file without using local-server the output is as follows.
[image]

Comment: Did `controller.js` is in same directory as html file, when your run it without server? What error do you get in the browser?

Comment: @csharpfolk Yes, it's in same directory as html file. see the edit

Comment: The problem is with loading angular.js library use 'https://' instead of '//'. If you use '//' browser will try to load using 'file://' protocol.

Comment: More in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902538/loading-local-files-with-javascript-without-a-web-server

Comment: @csharpfolk it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @csharpfolk suggested, the problem is with loading angular.js library use 'https://' instead of '//'. If you use '//' browser will try to load using 'file://' protocol.