# Run JavaScript Function in a different HTML file inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Currently I have two HTML files. One named index.html and another called editor.html

Inside index.html I have an iframe of editor.html Above this iframe is also a notification system I made. To run a notification it uses a function I created which can be used like so:

```
Notification("msg");
```

This function works great when I call it from inside of the index.html since the function modifies the index.html's html code (via .innerHTML). An issue shows up when I try and call it from the editor.html

Even with the editor.html added into index.html like this at the top of index.html:

```
<script src="editor.html"></script>
```

And I wrote this in the editor.html:

```
<script src="index.html"></script>
```

When I try and run the Notification function from the editor.html there is an error since the function is inside the index.html and modifies index.html, **not** editor.html.

Keep in mind that in each of the index.html and editor.html the javascript is in a  tag because there is other html within the file. Thanks and please ask questions if you need further confirmation.

Comment: One page can never run code on another one directly. They can only communicate and transfer data using [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). From inside the iframe, that would be `window.parent.postMessage()`, and from outside the iframe `document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage()`. You'll also need to attach an event listener for the "message" event on any receiving page.

Comment: Can you give an example using seperate index.html and editor.html? A way of passing the function and parameter on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works fine if the iframe and the container are in the same domain.**

You could put the definition of Notification function in a single external file, like main.js:

```js
function Notification( msg )
{
    var div = document.getElementById("notification-div") ;
    div.innerHTML = msg ;
    /* The important thing is make this to be the container window when
     * Notification is called, so document is the desired one.
     */
}
```

In index.html you should have the iframe and a div to print the notification text:

```html
<div id="notification-div"></div>
<iframe src="editor.html" width=300 height=200></iframe>
```

Then include main.js in index.html:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

In index.html you can call it directly, as long as this is window:

```js
Notification( "From index.html" ) ;
/* window will be this in the Notification function, so the call to
 * document.getElementById, will actually be window.document.getElementById
 */
```

In editor.html you can refer to the container window object as top. So this call will give the desired result:

```js
top.Notification( "From editor.html" ) ;
/* top will be this in the Notification function, so the call to
 * document.getElementById, will actually be top.document.getElementById
 */
```

Comment: When I tried this, this error message appeared in the console and running a notification from editor.html didn't work, but from index.html it did. I still **need** it to run from the editor.html. Here is the error: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: @AdamMikacich Are you testing with local files and Chrome? If so, please try the testing with Firefox or Edge.

Comment: I am testing with Local files. I'll upload it to my website and see if it works. Btw it is a **must** that this is compatible with Chrome (on the website, it's okay that it wont work locally though). I'll add a comment after the upload is complete and I run my tests.

Comment: @AdamMikacich You can also try the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902538/loading-local-files-with-javascript-without-a-web-server), if you want to continue using Chrome and local files for the testing.

Comment: You are awesome! It works great on my website! Thank you so much!!!! :D

Comment: @AdamMikacich Silly me. You don't have to include main.js in editor.html, only in index.html. I updated my answer accordingly.