# importing audio with p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I am trying to work on an audio visualization project and it seems that I cant even get the basics working. It gives me "Loading..." indefinitely! I have provided my sketch.js and index.html code below. Any idea on whats wrong?
[loading...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZdp.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
var song
var fft

function preload() {
  soundFormats('mp3')
  song = loadSound('/Users/noah/Desktop/programing/personals/p5_crazyy/fazoland.mp3')
}
 
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
  fft = new p5.FFT()
}

// command + q to display sovisual window
function draw() {
  background(0)
  stroke(255)

  var wave = fft.waveform()

  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    var index = floor(map(i, 0, width, 0, wave.length))
    var x = i
    var y = wave[index] * 300 + height  / 2
    point(x, y)
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (song.isPlaying()) {
    song.pause()
  } else {
    song.play()
  }
}
```

I have tried to add things such as the soundFormats('mp3') with no success.

Comment: What problem are you having? Is there an error or some undesirable behavior? You tell us what's wrong! I don't think reading a file off the file system will work--you'll probably need to [run a server](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server). Possible dupe: [How to play sounds in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549893/how-to-play-sounds-in-p5-js)

Comment: @ggorlen It gives me "Loading..." indefinitely! I will try to run a server, I have heard talks of this solution but I was simply too stubborn to try it haha, thanks.

Comment: Infinite loading generally means the audio file can't be found. Please try running a server and see if it resolves the issue. If it works for you, feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This post is better than the linked possible dupe, because the code is minimal, so I'd rather make that post a dupe of this rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from @ggorlen, hosting a server along with minor code changes resulted in the desired outcome. I used [simple web server](https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/simple-web-server/id1625925255?mt=12) which I downloaded from the mac store. Additionally I changed the file directory to:

```
var song
sound = loadSound('fazoland.mp3')
```

Hope this helps.