# Is it possible to share a website without hosting it?

Tags: html, css

So recently I started a project to expand my knowledge when it comes to HTML and CSS. I made a little website just for myself and I want to get some feedback from my friend.

I want him to be able to maybe click on a link and then get to my website (doesn't have to be a link). So I don't want to publish the website for anyone but for my friend or anyone that has that link or something like that.
I already heard about sharing files to someone on OneDrive and including all the code in it but my OneDrive is already out of storage so something different would be nice.

Comment: You can use Github, push your files there and let someone else clone your repository, and launch it on their machine . I would recommend you to read this before using **Github** [What is and How to use Github](https://blog.devmountain.com/what-is-github-and-how-do-you-use-it/)

Comment: You can use Firebase Hosting or Github Pages or any free hosting provider to host your website. After your website is hosted it will be available for your friend to see, without running the whole code.

Comment: People, read the title. The OP does not want to host the site.

Comment: See also [Loading local files with Javascript without a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19902538/215552)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use pages.github.com check the page is a small post and video tutorial on how to use it, greetings bro!